# Java Google Photos Api - How to cancel 'PhotosLibraryClient.initialize(settings)'?

Tags: java, kotlin, google-photos-api

I am developing an app in Java (Kotlin :X) that uses the Google Photos Api.

I am stuck in a flow where I may want to cancel the current client initialization attempt and try again.

```
val settings = PhotosLibrarySettings.newBuilder()
    .setCredentialsProvider(
        FixedCredentialsProvider.create(
            getUserCredentials(credentialsPath, SCOPES, email)
        )
    )
    .build()

// let the Thread hanging until a successful initialization :/
return PhotosLibraryClient.initialize(settings)
```

But unfortunately, I did not find any way to do this besides enveloping the `PhotosLibraryClient.initialize(settings)` call in a Thread and calling the deprecated method `Thread#stop()`.

If I do this call twice (on different threads), without successfully stopping one of the client initializations, the following exception is thrown: `java.io.IOException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)`.

---

How can I successfully stop a client initialization attempt without calling `Thread#stop()`?